# prove this Congruent equation

Tags: congruences

The question is:
if p is prime and odd number, prove that:
$1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +\ ... \ + (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv p + (p-1)! \ (mod\ p^2)$

I have no idea about this.
I was trying to use Wilson but no success...